# fflib_SObjectSelector - Not able to query for RecordType.DeveloperName

Tags: apex, fflib

So I was going through a selector class and came across an issue:

Sample selector class:

```
public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
    return new List<Schema.SObjectField>{
        Sample__c.Contact__c,
        Sample__c.RecordType.Name
    };
}
```

When I try to add :

```
public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
    return new List<Schema.SObjectField>{
        Sample__c.Contact__c,
        Sample__c.RecordType.Name,
        Sample__c.RecordType.DeveloperName

    };
}
```

It throws an exception on save -

> Variable does not exist: DeveloperName

Not sure if there is a utility method to add the record type dev name from the fflib_SObjectSelector class.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It seems that the only fields from the object are accessible on getSObjectFieldList.
in order to refer to related object's (for example Record Type) fields. Below thread might help - https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/issues/198

Comment: Neither `Sample__c.RecordType.Name` nor `Sample__c.RecordType.DeveloperName` entities are of type `Schema.SObjectField`. Cross-object fields cannot be expressed as `Schema.SObjectField`. But they can be included explicitly as strings using `selectField()` or `selectFields()` methods in the query builder.

Comment: Line: 138, Column: 1
fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'RecordType' for object

encountering this error

Comment: My bad, there was a silly mistake on the relation field query, seems to be working now.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Virtually all lookup relationships support the `Name` field - but that's it. Curiously `Account.RecordType.Name` is of type `SObjectField` and compiles correctly. `Account.RecordType.DeveloperName` or `Contact.Account.Website` do not compile.

A common way to retrieve relationship fields in fflib Selectors would be the following

```
public Sample__c[] selectByXXX(Set<Id> ids) {
    if (ids.isEmpty()) {return new List<Sample__c> ();}
    
    fflib_QueryFactory qF = newQueryFactory()
                                .selectField('RecordType.Name')
                                .selectField('RecordType.DeveloperName')
                                .setCondition('Id IN :ids');
    return Database.query(qf.toSOQL());
}
```

Alternatively, to centralize this for multiple selector methods (assumes you have a `RecordTypesSelector`.

```
public Sample__c[] selectByXXX(Set<Id> ids) {
    if (ids.isEmpty()) {return new List<Sample__c> ();}
    
    fflib_QueryFactory qF = newQueryFactory()
                                .setCondition('Id IN :ids');
    configureParents(qf);
    return Database.query(qf.toSOQL());
}

private void configureParents(fflib_QueryFactory qf) {
    new RecordTypesSelector().configureQueryFactoryFields(qf,'RecordType');
    // add other new XXXSelector for each parent
}
```